# Mongoose: Setting two-way references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an Express+Mongoose web app which has a number of models that depend on one another. Barring the possibility that I may not have designed my data correctly, I am looking to find out what is the best way for setting references between two objects that are related to one another.

I know that in my Schema obj, if I want a Schema to reference another Schema, I add `referenceId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ModelName' },` as a property. So far, when creating a model, I've been setting this property to the `id` I want to reference. For example: `obj.referenceId = someReferenceId; obj.save(...)`.

However, what if I have two independent schemas but they each have a reference to one another? What is the best way of setting these?

Right now, I am doing the below, but the code looks very messy:

```
objectASchema = Schema({
    objectBReference: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ObjectB' },
})
mongoose.model('ObjectA', objectASchema);

objectBSchema = Schema({
    objectAReference: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ObjectA' },
})
mongoose.model('ObjectB', objectBSchema);

// in a route/controller, and assuming we have an Object B created
// but you can see that if I don't have that, it gets messier
ObjectA.create(..., function(err, objectA) {
    objectA.objectBReference = objectBReferenceId;
    objectA.save(function(err) {
        ...
        ObjectB.findById({_id: objectBReferenceId}, function(err, objectB) {
            objectB.objectAReference = objectA._id;
            objectB.save(function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    // success! we're done here...
                }
            });
        })
    });
})
```

I am purposefully avoiding embedding in this case because in my app, I am operating under the assumption that I need to query these objects separately, without having to load the data from either.

My use case is akin to having something like a `Product`, `Review`, and `User` model, where each of these references the other, but is not necessarily embedded in the other. Queries can be something like: Get all the reviews for this product, or all the reviews from this user. This means reviews cannot be embedded in a User or Product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With MongooseJS you can create both of them locally, associate them and then save both to the DB in parallel using a promise (this uses the native [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object but an library would work):

```
var objectA = new ObjectA();
var objectB = new ObjectB();

objectA.objectBReference = objectB;
objectB.objectAReference = objectA;

Promise.all([
  objectA.save(),
  objectB.save()
]).then(function(savedObjects) {
  // Do something to celebrate?
}).catch(function(err) {
  // one or both errored
});
```

UPDATE: You can also use nested saves if desired. The key point is that the IDs are generated locally and can be associated to other documents without saving them first.

```
var objectA = new ObjectA();
var objectB = new ObjectB();

objectA.objectBReference = objectB;
objectB.objectAReference = objectA;

objectA.save(function (err, objA) {
  if (err) { ... }

  objectB.save(function (err, objB) {
    if (err) { ... }

    // Do something to celebrate?
  });
});
```

Comment: Are promises the only way I can overcome nested callback saves, or is there a more appropriate way of doing this in Mongo?

Comment: @tsurantino You can still use nested saves if you wish. I used a promise to illustrate that saving each was independent of the other (i.e. that the IDs to associate them are generated locally). Updated to show nested saving as well.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for explaining your answer more. I ended up also exploring Promises.

Comment: Sweet, I had hoped you could accomplish this with promises. Thanks!